# How to validate transaction manually in hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Would you tell me, if fabric does manual transaction validation?
i.e: Before a transaction could be archived in the ledger, it must be signed by the organization which evolved in the endorsement policies. This process of validation, by signing the transaction, could it be done manually by a decision of the user ( Clicking button )?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is possiable,but why do you need to do this,according to my idea,if you want to validation transaction manual,It is better and easy to do this before you proposal transaction.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. yes, i think that you are right. it's about a document flow, it can be created and filled first, then it must be approved by another group of users, they read it, then if it's okey, they validate the document. so a manual validation means a document validation by the user examinator of the docuement.